# Reordering List Updates an Unrelated Dictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, unity-game-engine

When I reorder a list by adding a value, a dictionary with the same value type updates.

Here is the code that I used. After swapping the order of lst in the Unity inspector, "dict["daveID"].name" displays "Jessica".

```
public class Check : MonoBehaviour
{

    Dictionary<string, Person> dict = new Dictionary<string, Person>();
    [SerializeField] List<Person> lst = new List<Person>();

    private void Start()
    {
        dict.Add("daveID", new Person("Dave"));
        dict.Add("jessID", new Person("Jessica"));

        foreach (var i in dict)
        {
            lst.Add(i.Value);
        }
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        GUILayout.Label("daveID's string (dct): " + dict["daveID"].name + " lst version: " + lst[0].name);
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Person
{
    public string name;

    public Person(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

My question is, why is the list and dictionary linked like this?

**Update**

I have edited my question for clarity. I understand that the objects are references, but surely reordering a list will not affect a dictionary's key/value pairs.

Comment: _"why is the list and dictionary linked like this?"_ - because they're reference-types:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c

Comment: ...you are adding the *same objects* to the list.  you are not creating `new` ones